# google sign in returns an unhandled exception, i am on flutter with the firebase google sign in

Tags: widget, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

[image: these are the errors on logcat]

this is the code with the method to sign in with google account.
  included with its statistics, any ideas i can solve this log in problem???

```
     void main() {
     runApp(new FriendlychatApp());
      }

      Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
      GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
      if (user == null)
      user = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
      if (user == null) {
      user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      analytics.logLogin();
      }
      if (await auth.currentUser() == null) {
      GoogleSignInAuthentication credentials =
      await googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication;
      await auth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: credentials.idToken,
      accessToken: credentials.accessToken,
      );
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry it didn't help, try and follow this example [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/main.dart) and make sure you integrate your app correctly with firebase as well like you have enabled GoogleAuthentication in the Authentication section and change the function to

```
Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount user =  await googleSignIn.currentUser;
  if (user == null)
    user = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  if (user == null) {
    user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    analytics.logLogin();
  }

  var response = await auth.currentUser();
  if (response.uid == null) {
    GoogleSignInAuthentication credentials =
    await googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication;
    await auth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: credentials.idToken,
      accessToken: credentials.accessToken,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use await for this line mentioned below as well.

```
GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
```

so you should actually use.

```
GoogleSignInAccount user = await googleSignIn.currentUser;
```

let me know if this helped,

Many Thanks,
Mahi.